# Invoke an Auto-launched Flow in Apex?

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow

This seems like it should be easy but I'm having a lot of trouble finding any resources from after 2014. It's a rather simple scenario. I have a Flow and need to invoke it from an Apex Trigger + Class (it's before delete/after undelete, so Process Builder won't suffice).

It's a very simple process too. Just grab a field value, assign it to the Flow variable. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try anything?  What type of issues you are facing

Comment: I'm brand new to Apex (and coding). I haven't tried anything yet because I have found zero resources showing how to achieve it. There was something involving Controllers and VF, but I don't have any experience or even cursory knowledge of those... I was hoping for a simple way to define a method, pass in parameters and invoke with a Trigger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To invoke a flow from a class and pass in values to the Flow's variables:

```
Flow.Interview flow = new Flow.Interview.MyFlowApiName(new map<String,Object> 
                                                {'vAccountId' => aId});     
flow.start();

// after flow has executed, fetch values from Flow's variables 
//       (assumes flow creates an Order and a Contact)
Order ord   = (Order) flow.getVariableValue('oOrder');
Contact c   = (Contact) flow.getVariableValue('oContact');
```

Doc refs: [Getting variables from flows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_visualworkflow_vars.htm?search_text=flow) and [Setting variables into Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/flow_interview_class.htm#flow_interview_class)

Your flow variables to be declared of type input/output as appropriate.  Reference to variables is *case-sensitive*