# How does flow accept input parameters from batch class

Tags: trigger, batch, visual-workflow

I have an apex trigger and a batch class. I am running apex trigger on contact, sending it to batch class and from batch class sending the parameters to flow.

Trigger:

```
trigger BulkContactsLoad on Contact (after insert) {

   Map<id, Contact> contacts = new Map<id, Contact>([Select Id, FirstName, 
   LastName From Contact Where Id IN : 
   Trigger.newMap.keySet()]);

   System.debug('contacts'+ contacts);
   System.debug('hello');

if (contacts.size() > 0){
    Database.executeBatch(new SendContactToFlow(contacts));
}



}
```

Batch class:

```
global class SendContactToFlow implements Database.Batchable<sObject>

{

    Map<id,contact> IdContactMapBatch=new Map<id,contact>();
    global  SendContactToFlow(Map<id,contact> IdContactMap){
    IdContactMapBatch=IdContactMap;
}
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT id,firstname, lastname, middlename, email from contact where id in:IdContactMapBatch.keySet()]);
}
 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<contact> scope)

{

     Flow.Interview.FLOWNAME theFlow;
    // Call my Flow
    for(Contact contact: scope){
        Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
       //Put the Record ID from the Query into the RecordId variable in the flow
        params.put('RecordId', contact.Id);
        theFlow = new Flow.Interview.FLOWNAME(params);

        theFlow.start();
        }
    }

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
}


}
```

**How do I make the flow accept the input parameters(Contact Id and Contact object)? Even if I make variables in flow for Contact Id and contact object. How do those variables get value from batch class.

Also I know that it is not recommended to call batch class from apex trigger,  I might add a check there to check how many batches are already in the flex queue before sending other batches.

Comment: did you look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/161194/2602 ? Each flow variable defined as "available for input" corresponds to a key in the map (case sensitive).  Pass only Id and let the flow query the contact

Comment: ok I will try that. Quick question, should I be calling flow in execute method or finish method?

Comment: use the `execute()` method as each invocation of `execute()` is a transaction with only 200 contacts and that helps prevent limits exceptions

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. I was able to successfully send the parameters. Also I was trying to call screen flow due to which it was throwing me error. As soon as I changed it to autolaunched flow and called that from batch class, it worked.

Comment: you should post an answer showing your corrected code