# How to set variable from flow to Apex and Call flow from Apex?

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, automation, invocablevariable

My flow type is **autolaunched flow** , the goal of the flow is to send Emails.

[image]

I want to call this flow from Apex , besides i want to fill these fields : *EmailAddresses* and *SenderAddress* in Apex and pass it to flow - How can i achieve this as i didn't find any documentation.

Comment: Have you checked this post? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161189/invoke-an-auto-launched-flow-in-apex. I don't think you're correct about the documentations.

Answer (score 2):

You use the [Flow.Interview](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/flow_interview_class.htm) class to create and execute flows. First, create a Map of parameters to use, create a new Interview, and then start it. Here's the example from the documentation:

```
  Map<String, Object> inputs = new Map<String, Object>();
  inputs.put('AccountID', myAccount);
  inputs.put('OpportunityID', myOppty);
  
  Flow.Interview.Calculate_discounts myFlow = 
    new Flow.Interview.Calculate_discounts(inputs);
  myFlow.start();
```

Comment: If my case , i want to fill *EmailAddresses* and *SenderAddress* with Case's custom fields 
So my code should be like :  `Map<String, Object> inputs = new Map<String, Object>();
  inputs.put('Case.Customfield', myAccount);
  inputs.put('Case.Customfield', myOppty);
  
  Flow.Interview.Calculate_discounts myFlow = 
    new Flow.Interview.MyFLOWNAME(inputs);
  myFlow.start();`  

**myAccount** and **myOppty** are Flow's variables - can you confirm?

Comment: @Adam You need the API name for each input variable (you've got the key/value backwards), it would look more like: `inputs.put('emailAddresses',new String[] { myCase.ContactEmail }); inputs.put('senderAddress', UserInfo.getUserEmail());`